# How to effectively loop through each pixel for saving time with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

As you know looping through each pixels and accessing their values with opencv takes too long. As a beginner I'm trying to learn opencv myself when I tried this approach it took me around 7-10 seconds of time to loop through image and perform operations.

code is as below

```
original_image = cv2.imread(img_f)

image = np.array(original_image)
for y in range(image.shape[0]):
    for x in range(image.shape[1]):
        # remove grey background
        if 150 <= image[y, x, 0] <= 180 and \
                150 <= image[y, x, 1] <= 180 and \
                150 <= image[y, x, 2] <= 180:
            image[y, x, 0] = 0
            image[y, x, 1] = 0
            image[y, x, 2] = 0

        # remove green dashes
        if image[y, x, 0] == 0 and \
                image[y, x, 1] == 169 and \
                image[y, x, 2] == 0:
            image[y, x, 0] = 0
            image[y, x, 1] = 0
            image[y, x, 2] = 0
```

in above code i'm just trying to remove grey and green pixel colors.

I found similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924991/opencv-python-pixel-by-pixel-loop-is-slow) but im not able to understand how to use numpy in my usecase as i'm beginner in python and numpy.

Any help or suggestion for solving this will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Read about numpy at https://numpy.org/doc/

Comment: np.where searches for pixels that match the condition and you can then set those to some value or color. See https://sparkbyexamples.com/numpy/numpy-where-multiple-conditions/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of NumPy's vectorized operations to eliminate all loops which should be much faster.

```py
# Remove grey background
is_grey = ((150 <= image) & (image <= 180)).all(axis=2, keepdims=True)
image = np.where(is_grey, 0, image)

# Remove green dashes
is_green_dash = (image[..., 0] == 0) & (image[..., 1] == 169) & (image[..., 2] == 0)
is_green_dash = is_green_dash[..., np.newaxis]  # append a new dim at the end
image = np.where(is_green_dash, 0, image)
```

Both invocations of `np.where` rely on NumPy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply numpy filtering to image. In your scenario it would be:

```py
mask_gray = (
    (150 <= image[:, :, 0]) & (image[:, :, 0] <= 180) & 
    (150 <= image[:, :, 1]) & (image[:, :, 1] <= 180) & 
    (150 <= image[:, :, 2]) & (image[:, :, 2] <= 180)
)

image[mask_gray] = 0

mask_green = (
    (image[:, :, 0] == 0) &
    (image[:, :, 1] == 169) &
    (image[:, :, 2] == 0)
)

image[mask_green] = 0
```

`mask_gray` and `mask_green` here are boolean masks

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on writing your own loops...

You could just use **`numba`**. It's a JIT compiler for Python code.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def your_function(input):
    ...
    return output

input = cv.imread(...) # yes this will shadow the builtin of the same name
output = your_function(input)
```

The first time you call `your_function`, it'll take a second to compile. All further calls are blazingly fast.